# name 'my_class' is not defined

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I recently started a django course and started a login interface with product registration. While using the functions within the same application, everything worked fine (in this case, I created everything within the users app).
I created the products app and the inconsistencies started.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib import messages
from .import models

@login_required
def ListagemProdutos(request):
    ListaItens = classeproduto.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'baselist.html', {'produtos': ListaItens})

@login_required
def produtoView(request, id):
    item = get_object_or_404(produto, pk=id)
    return render(request, 'produto.html', {'produto': item})
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .import views

urlpatterns = [    
     path('', views.ListagemProdutos, name='listagemprodutos'),
     path('produto/<int:id>', views.produtoView, name="produto-view"),
]
```

and models.py

```
from django.db import models

class classeproduto(models.Model):

    STATUS = (
        ('Ativo','Ativo'),
        ('Inativo','Inativo'),
    )


    descricaoresumida = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    ativo = models.CharField(
        max_length=7,
        choices=STATUS,
    )

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.descricaoresumida
```

I already reviewed the code and didn't identify the error =/
Can you help me?

```
NameError at /produtos/
name 'classeproduto' is not defined
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://192.168.15.90:8000/produtos/
Django Version: 4.2.4
Exception Type: NameError
Exception Value:    
name 'classeproduto' is not defined
Exception Location: C:\Users\Elinton\Desktop\projeto-gestao\gestao\produtos\views.py, line 10, in ListagemProdutos
Raised during:  produtos.views.ListagemProdutos
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Elinton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe
Python Version: 3.11.4
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Elinton\\Desktop\\projeto-gestao\\gestao',
 'C:\\Users\\Elinton\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\python311.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Elinton\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Elinton\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Elinton\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311',
 'C:\\Users\\Elinton\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python311\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\Elinton\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 12 Sep 2023 23:17:59 +0000
```

Comment: If you've just imported `models`, you'd need to refer to the class as `models.classeproduto`.  Or, you could explicitly import `models.classeproduto` and then be able to refer to just `classeproduto`.

Comment: I identified the problem. As I changed from an existing app to one created now, I had not previously run makemigrations/migrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. change `classeproduto` to `models.classeproduto`
2. change `produto` to `models.produto`
3. change `from .import models` to `from . import models`